# Okta bearer token authentication working in local but not on Azure app service

Tags: c#, .net-core, okta, azure-appservice

Below is the code is startup for enabling okta authentication,

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.Authority = _settings.Authority;
           options.Audience = _settings.Audience;


           options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
           {
               RoleClaimType = "Role"
           };
       });
```

Same piece of code is working in my local and on premise server. But same is not working in azure app service all the secured api requests are resulting in 500 internal server error.

In serilog logs i could see debug info as 'AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.'

Any idea what could be the reason?

below is the attached screenshot on my local vs azure app service request,

[image]

Comment: Check your Azure configuration settings and see if the app setting for _settings.Authority is present

Comment: Settings are present. No issues with that.

Comment: You're not getting a 401, you're getting a 500. Can you ping the api at all?

Comment: Yes I am getting 500 for secured api end points. Unsecured api end points which have allowanonymous attribute on them are working fine.

Comment: One more thing same piece of build copy works on on premise IIS server with out any issue.

Comment: If you remove the [Authorized] attribute from the secured ones, can you reach them? If so, I'd attach a debugger to the Azure app. If you don't have the JwtBearerEvents configured inside .AddJwtBearer, I would add them as well and break it inside one or all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure app service environment app does not have access to below url,

https://orgname.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration

Once I enable access to that in firewall it's working.